# How can I let Kibana read custom index for metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I deployed Elasticsearch and Kibana 7.10.1. And I am streaming cloudwatch metrics data (raw json) to Elasticsearch.

The metric raw data format looks like:

```
{
          "metric_stream_name" : "metric-stream-elk",
          "account_id" : "264100014405",
          "region" : "ap-southeast-2",
          "namespace" : "AWS/DynamoDB",
          "metric_name" : "ReturnedRecordsCount",
          "dimensions" : {
            "Operation" : "GetRecords",
            "StreamLabel" : "2021-06-18T01:12:31.851",
            "TableName" : "dev-dms-iac-events"
          },
          "timestamp" : 1624924620000,
          "value" : {
            "count" : 121,
            "sum" : 0,
            "max" : 0,
            "min" : 0
          },
          "unit" : "Count"
        }
```

I can see that these raw data are saved in Elasitcsearch with a custom index name `aws-metrics-YYYY-MM-DD`. Now how can I let Kibana read metrics from this index?

I don't want to use `metricbeat` because it queries metrics from AWS. My event flow is streaming AWS metrics to Elasticsearch. How can I achieve that?